# iPhone incoming call view class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I´m developing a theos tweak and I would like to modify mainly the incoming call view (iOS 5 and iOS 6). I would appreciate the name of the class that handle this view for hook into it´s methods. I already try `MPIncomingPhoneCallController` and `SBCallAlertDisplay` and none of those had worked for me.

[image: incoming call view screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you dump the headers on the `InCallService.app` (phone app), you will see a `PHAlert` class with a method called `- (void)showOnViewController:(id)arg1;`.  This will display the "incoming call" view on top of any `UIViewController`.  You can use this with the frontmost application: `[[SpringBoard sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication]`.